# Retrieve button state (clicked or not clicked) with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button. I'd like to know if exists a variable that if I click this button it changes automatically its value. For example if I clicked the button the variable is set to 1 if I've not clicked the button variable is 0.

And I would retrieve this variable with JQuery or Javascript.

Comment: There is no "automatic variable", but it's easily coded if you want a code example?

Comment: The question you've asked in the title is different than the one in your description

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
var x = 0;
$('#buttonID').on('click', function (event) {
        x = 1;
});
```

Comment: This is for "a button", one button, that's why I wrote `#` (buttonID). Or did I read wrong?

Comment: Oh.  Okay.  I would have made it work for multiple buttons, that's all.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
var clickCount = 0;

$("#myButton").click(function() { 
    clickCount++;
});
```

Or just

```
clickCount = 1;
```

If you don't want to increment it past 1

Answer (score 0):

There is no variable. But you can use javascript to determine or do something after the button is clicked

Answer (score 0):

for all button

```
var click= 0;
$(':button').on('click', function (event) {
        click = 1;
});
```

Comment: button can be `<button>` tag, better is to use as selector: `$(':button')` if you want to get all buttons

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of doing this but the easy one to retrieve then clicked button is to set a class for example:

```
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).addClass('clicked');
});

var $clickedButtons = $('.clicked');
```

Or using data attribute, you have to set it in DOM:

```
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).attr('data-clicked',true);
});

var $clickedButtons = $(':button[data-clicked]');
```

You could use the data object too:

```
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    $(this).data('clicked',true);
});

var $clickedButtons = $(':button').filter(function(){
        return $(this).data('clicked');
    });
```

To show you the 'many ways', as any javascript object can be override, you could just do:

```
$(':button').on('click',function(){
    this.clicked = true;
});

var $clickedButtons = $(':button').filter(function(){
        return this.clicked;
    });
```